# Как открыть файлы *.pdf, *.doc на нужной странице?

Tags: c++, qt, gui, qt4

Открываю файл в Windows в приложении по умолчанию: `QDesktopServices::openUrl('c:\tmp\noname.pdf')`

В браузере можно открыть нужную страницу `c:\tmp\noname.pdf#123`
где 123 - номер страницы. Как сделать то же самое в Qt?

То же самое с `*.doc` - как открыть нужную страницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, боюсь это зависит от браузера и Qt тут не поможет. Попытался открыть pdf в Firefox с указанием страницы – он не смог, просто pdf смог открыть.

Как вариант, запустите ехе вашего браузера передав ему в параметр тот путь с pdf с указанной страницей

**Update.**

Для запуска исполняемого файла в Qt, используйте [QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached):

```cpp
QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\pip.exe", 
                        QStringList() << "install grab");
```

Поигрался я у себя и вот получилось. Проблема была с путем к ехе -- его нужно было в кавычки оборачивать, иначе не работало:

```cpp
QString path = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\"";
QString file = "C:\\Users\\book.pdf";
QProcess::startDetached(path, QStringList() << "/A" << "page=3" << file);
```

Comment: мне желательно все-таки открывать pdf не через браузер, а через приложение по умолчанию, например, `adobe acrobat`. у  `adobe acrobat`есть параметры http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf  но я не знаю, как их ему передать из Qt. в `firefox` я вбивал в адресную строку `c:\tmp\noname.pdf#123`, файл без проблем открывался на нужной странице. Запуск exe не самый лучший вариант, т.к. я не могу заранее знать, какая программа установлена на компьютере для просмотра pdf, и где лежит его exe.

Comment: Нашел вот такой вариант http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/?FID=1&PAGE_NAME=read&TID=47684 там запуск через shell, как это реализовать на Qt в Windows? Получается, мне нужно попробовать найти exe для acrobat reader по стандартному пути, если он есть - передать ему параметры. если его нет - то запустить браузер по умолчанию.

Comment: Кстати, в спеке по акробату написано, что нужно так открывать pdf с указанной страницей: `http://noname.pdf#page=123`

Comment: хм, интересно, спасибо. в браузере, работают оба варианта `#123` и `#page=123`, но пока только непосредственно в адресной строке. через `QDesktopServices::openUrl('c:\tmp\noname.pdf#page=123')`, конечно, не открывается, как и `QDesktopServices::openUrl('c:\tmp\noname.pdf#123')`.

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример запуска исполняемых файлов

Comment: Добавил пример запуска pdf с указанием страницы

Comment: спасибо, получилось отлично. добавил еще дополнительные проверки на существование exe-файла и pdf-файла. Если exe не существует - открываю без указания страницы в приложении по умолчанию. Осталось придумать, как сделать то же самое для *.doc